# How do I match a column entry from one df to a different df; and if they're the same, append another column's entry from the first df to the 2nd df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merging-data

**CONTEXT:**

I have two dataframes that have the following set up:

df1 looks like this...and goes on for about 3500 rows:

```
| id1 | id2   | 
|:----|------:|
| a   | name1 |  
| b   | name2 | 
| c   | name3 | 
| d   | name4 | 
| e   | name5 |   
| f   | name6 |
```

df2 looks like this...and goes on for about 4000 rows and about 8 columns

```
| id1 | ranktrial1   | ranktrial2   | ...
|:----|-------------:|-------------:| ...
| a   | rank1        |rank1         | ...
| b   | rank2        |rank2         | ...
| c   | rank3        |rank3         | ...
| d   | rank4        |rank4         | ...
| e   | rank5        |rank5         | ...  
| f   | rank6        |rank6         | ...
```

*NOTE1: some of the id1s, do not have id2s. Meaning they'll be NaNs when they're mapped; and I'll just drop them whenever I get to that step. I don't know if this is relevant, but I just wanted to add it in case it was.*

**QUESTION:**

I need to append/join/place (don't know correct jargon here) the corresponding id2 names to the second dataframe, iff the id1 entry == id1 entry of df2. How do I do this?

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
| id1 | id2   | ranktrial1   | tranktrail2  | ...
|:----|------:|-------------:|-------------:| ...
| a   | name1 | rank1        | rank1        | ...  
| b   | name2 | rank2        | rank2        | ...
| c   | name3 | rank3        | rank3        | ...
| d   | name4 | rank4        | rank4        | ...
| e   | name5 | rank5        | rank5        | ...
| f   | name6 | rank6        | rank6        | ...
```

I feel as if this is probably really simple and I'm being a bit of a doofus, as I am a novice Pythoner. However, I have not been able to use similar question's responses to achieve my goal. It is quite likely my fault though :p

Thanks in advance for your help!

*edits* changed 4000 entries --> 4000 rows. LIkewise for 3500 entries

Comment: Did you read about merge?

Comment: Yes! And I have tried numerous methods that I thought would give results that I had hoped. Either, i'd create an empty dataframe; or I'd make a dataframe that did more of a concatenation.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are dropping the missing bits afterwards, this is an inner join and can be accomplished with `merge`.  By default, `merge` uses all commonly named columns.  In this case, the only commonly named column is `id1`.  Also, `how='inner'` si also the default.

```
df1.merge(df2)

  id1    id2 ranktrial1 tranktrail2
0   a  name1      rank1       rank1
1   b  name2      rank2       rank2
2   c  name3      rank3       rank3
3   d  name4      rank4       rank4
4   e  name5      rank5       rank5
5   f  name6      rank6       rank6
```

You could be more explicit with

```
df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='id1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt result! I feel as if I had tried some of the merge (and merge combinations). But let me give it a spin!

Comment: Yea, this doesn't work as intended. This creates an empty dataframe that looks something like this (with the indexes like the following:)

   ` |id1|id2|ranktrial1|ranktrial2|...etc...` 

and then everything is empty.

I don't know why this occurs.

Comment: Then that means something else is going on.  Likely, you are importing a file and you end up with one column that is a big string per row.  You don't know what to expect so assume that it is a dataframe.  If I'm right, and this is a file, show us what the file looks like and we'll show you how to parse it.  Then this suggestion should work.  If I'm wrong... then idk what to do.

Comment: The first file with the id1/id2 columns is a RData object that I brought in and converted with rpy2 to a pandas dataframe. After I converted it, I cut out some unecessary data so it would only have the id1 and id2 columns.

The other file was a tab delimited .txt file, that I brought in with pd.read_csv and had the sep as '\t'

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7a879545491365af5ef80864750fde70

https://gyazo.com/544867157d206909c9c697f3cf36b073

Screenshots from the Spyder IDE, showing the two dataframes and what they look like (obviously, not with the generic names I have used in this example)

Comment: and with a sample of the "combo" dataframe, with the merge function used:


https://gyazo.com/68ac78e474973c5e50697ee47cd35cbf

Comment: My only other guess is that your ids are strings in one df and ints in the other.  Try `df1.astype({'id1': str}).merge(df2.astype({'id1': str}))`

Comment: This makes sense. 
I'll give it a try when I can get back to my computer. 
Thanks!

Comment: Wow. I think that was the issue! My next question is does this "default" method automatically drop rows that contain NaN? Because the size is about what I would expect. I am just double checking.

Again, thank you SO MUCH for your time and contribution.

Comment: default is `'inner'` so yes.